# Adding point shapefile layer to polygon shapefile window in R?

Tags: r, spatstat

I'm new to Spatstat for R and I'm trying to add a point layer to a window I've created from a polygon. I see questions like this have been asked before but I still can't get what I need from the responses given.  So far I have:

```
##Run libraries: 
library(“spatstat”)
library(“maptools”)
library(“sp”)
library(“rgdal”)

##set the working directory
setwd(“Z:/CP/spatstat/data/”)

##read in the shapefiles
Points <- readOGR(getwd(), "MyPointShapefile")
StudyArea <- readOGR(getwd(), "MyPolygonShapefile")

##create the window from polygon shp
w <- as.owin(StudyArea)
```

How do I add the two together so the points are projected in the window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just coerce "Points" to a ppp object using "w" as the window.

```
w <- as.owin(StudyArea)
  pts.ppp <- as.ppp(coordinates(Points), w)
    plot(pts.ppp)
```